# why the filter function ignore the item on the react component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a comment list with 4 items, "nestComments 3" will print 4 items, but it prints 3 items after the filter, why?

[image]

```
console.log("nestComments 3", commentList);
    const result = commentList.filter((comment) => {
      // console.log("nestComments 3 commnetList", commentList);
      console.log("nestComments 3 commnet", comment);
      return comment.parentId === null;
    });
console.log("nestComments 4", result);
```

I think there might be something related to setState statement here

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    // force render
    let { comments } = this.state;
    comments.push({
      id: 7,
      parentId: null
    });
    comments = this.nestComments(comments);
    // this.setState(({ comments }) => ({
    //   comments: this.nestComments(comments)
    // }));
    this.setState({ comments });
    console.log("2nd", comments, this.nestComments(comments));
    this.setState({ comments: this.nestComments(comments) });
    // !important: React will ignore the update after setState
    comments.push({
      id: 8,
      parentId: null
    });
    // this.setState({ comments: this.nestComments(comments) });
  }
```

my full code is here

https://github.com/dotku/lab-react/blob/fa1b25f/src/features/commentList/index.js#L94-L101

Comment: Your github file is 404.

Comment: Sorry, I make it public righ tnow